# How can I see and edit the User's Additional information from Firebase consol that was edited programmatically

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase Authentication in my app. I used method like `setDisplayName` in my app so that user can change the user's name himself through the app. But, the problem is that I can't access this name through my console. I can't edit it. There are simple columns in Firebase console like,

> identifiers,providers,UID,Providers,Signed In.

There is no column for User Name. How can I access this information through console?

Comment: Hey! I believe the best way for that is to create a collection name `users` and create your user's profile information there.

You can have the information living in both places, basically, on the Firebase Auth you will have the user's email and UID and on your `users` collection you can have everything else.

Make sure the ID for the user in your collection matches the UID on the Firebase Auth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase console shows only limited information about each user profile. The rest of the information is only available when you access the profile through a Firebase API, or export the data.

Keep in mind that Firebase provides [Admin SDKs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin), which you can run on your development machine to accomplish simple administrative tasks such as this.